# Mapper class not found

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, classnotfoundexception

Sometimes my MR job complains that MyMapper class in not found.
And that i have to give job.setJarByClass(MyMapper.class); to tell it to load it from my jar file.

cloudera@cloudera-vm:/tmp/translator$ hadoop jar MapReduceJobs.jar translator/input/Portuguese.txt translator/output
13/06/13 03:36:57 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/06/13 03:36:57 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/13 03:36:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201305100422_0043
13/06/13 03:36:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/13 03:37:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201305100422_0043_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mapreduce.variousformats.keyvaluetextinputformat.MyMapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:601)

Question : Why does it happen. Why doesn't it always tell me to load it from my jar file.
Is there some best practices for tackling these kind of issues. Also if i am using some 3rd party libraries , will i have to do this for them as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

Use the following to add all the jar dependencies from (for example) current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't have machine access to do "hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar |"
If i am bundling all the external jars inside my jar file, will i still have use job.setJarByClass or hadoop will take care of loading it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `job.setJarByClass` is necessary. So that hadoop will copy your jar to the task trackers. If you does not invoke `job.setJarByClass`, hadoop will think your jar is in the classpath of task trackers, so it does not copy your jar.

Comment: Agreed, but why is it so. Sometimes i don't even need to use job.setJarByClass. I am curious to know how does it sometimes automatically comes to know that it has to load that class from the jar file.

Comment: As I know, it works without `setJarByClass` on single-node cluster, if you have several nodes, you should call this method.